# How do I disable super dev mode so that I can use my Gwt module in a separate web project

Tags: java, maven, gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I am building a web module with GWT 2.7.0.

I want to copy the generated module folder in my maven output folder i.e. target and refer it in a separate web app.

When I try to do so it keeps popping up Couldn't load from server dialog.

I added

```
<superdevmode>false</superdevmode>
```

and added this to my module file

```
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="false"/>
```

but still no luck. I am still getting the popup.

Any clues ?

thanks,

Gautam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recompiled the gwt project with the same set of flags.

Prior to it I did a mvn clean and ofcourse I didn't do gwt:run only -

clean compile gwt:compile

then copied the produced module folder to the other project webapp and added the nocache.js to the host page.

Although the limitation is if you want sourcemaps and debugging support you still need to run codeserver in the project and thus you will need super dev mode enabled.